# Free / low-cost OLAP cube viewer

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development, reporting

I need to select an OLAP cube viewer to integrate with my company's in-house software (we have a team of devs to do so). It needs to be browser-based and I'd prefer to use one with no plugin/install  dependencies such as Flash (JS only on the client side). Open source with a commercial-friendly license would also be preferable, but a low-cost closed source is an option.

Anyone have any good experiences / recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The Syncfusion [OlapClient](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/olapclient/defaultfunctionalities) control can be used for browsing Olap cubes.

[image: Syncfusion OlapClient]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 'Kyubit Business Intelliegence' OLAP web based client with great visualizations and analytic features.

[www.kyubit.com](http://www.kyubit.com)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Power Bi** could be a fit: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/
Can import a wide variety of sources.

Note: I've only used it to import ODATA sources